# CodedUI Visual Studio: How to wait for browser load

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I was wondering if anyone new how to make the Automation Script in CodedUI wait for the web page to load before continuing on with the script.

So I fill out a form and press the "Continue" button, then the script times out because it gives up waiting. I realise I could use Playback.wait but then I would have code this each time I click continue.... and I have hundreds of scripts! Something similar to Seleniums WaitforBrowserLoad but for CodedUI

C# CodedUI in VS 2012

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use:

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this makes my tests run in super slow mode :-(.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, Coded UI is excellent about waiting for page loads to be complete before continuing test execution. That said, you can force a wait for a specific control to exist with [`WaitForControlExist`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee823173.aspx) method. This method is a member of the base class of all UI controls, [`UITestControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Comment: There are several other `WaitForControl...` methods that allow waiting for other conditions.

Comment: Don't limit yourself to just waiting for a control.  Coded UI has more wait options to offer. [MSDN - Making Coded UI Tests Wait For Specific Events During Playback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg131072.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your issue could be fixed if you create a settings file and increase the timeout.

Directions Here: [Specifying Test Settings in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx)

You could also call the WaitForControlReady method on the browser window object.

ex:

```
_browserWindow.WaitForControlReady(60000); //Should wait for 1 min
```